# Why does dcos package fail with "URL is unreachable: Max retries exceeded with url: /package/list" after installing another DC/OS cluster?

Tags: dcos

After working with [dcos-vagrant](https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant) for local DC/OS cluster provisioning for some time I installed a 3-node minimal DC/OS cluster.

Now, whenever I execute `dcos package list` (or any other `dcos package` command) I'm getting the following error:

> URL [http://m1.dcos/package/describe] is unreachable: HTTPConnectionPool(host='m1.dcos', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /package/describe (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))

Why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You should check your DC/OS configuration using `dcos config show`.

```
$ dcos config show
core.dcos_acs_token ********
core.dcos_url http://m1.dcos
```

Change `core.dcos_url` to the new DC/OS master URL using `dcos config set <name> <value>`.

```
$ dcos config set core.dcos_url http://localhost:8000
[core.dcos_url]: changed from 'http://m1.dcos' to 'http://localhost:8000'

$ dcos package list
Your core.dcos_acs_token is invalid. Please run: `dcos auth login`

$ dcos auth login

Please go to the following link in your browser:

    http://localhost:8000/login?redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

Enter OpenID Connect ID Token: [paste your token here]
Login successful!

$ dcos package list
NAME   VERSION          APP     COMMAND  DESCRIPTION
kafka  1.1.16-0.10.0.0  ---     kafka    Apache Kafka running on DC/OS
spark  1.0.6-2.0.2      /spark  spark    Spark is a fast and general cluster computing system for Big Data.  Documentation: https://docs.mesosphere.com/current/usage/service-guides/spark/
```